# Can you just rely on battery BMS's undervoltage protection for normal use

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

Let's say you buy a lithium battery with BMS circuit included. The BMS protects against undervoltage (and other things) and only 2 wire-leads come out of the battery (so no seperate charging wire). eg. [Lithium battery](https://benl.rs-online.com/web/p/speciality-size-rechargeable-batteries/1449405/?cm_mmc=BE-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_BE_NL_Batteries_%26_Chargers_Whoop-_-(BE:Whoop!)%20Speciality%20Size%20Rechargeable%20Batteries-_-1449405&matchtype=&aud-827186183926:pla-333331382340&gclid=CjwKCAjwi9-HBhACEiwAPzUhHLPOJzBi0nWfA0iBeJQGcLlPV1qaFzT3ZTfwN5ckwjlgnSTor51jEhoCcSYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Is it okay to use this in a self-designed electronic device with no further attention for the voltage of the battery and no means of disconnecting the battery from the device electronically on the device side?

On one side I would assume yes and use the UVP threshold as the voltage when the battery is dead. But I heard others say that you should better not trip this protection and check the battery voltage on the device itself and let itself shut down when the voltage is near the UVP voltage. This would be because when in UVP kicks in the battery disconnects itself entirely and no recharging could be done + the battery lifespan diminishes.

Comment: *you should better not trip this protection* I agree with this, the BMS cutout voltage is generally quite low (in the order of 2.7 V) and at that voltage your battery is **very, very empty**. It is a "last resort" to prevent immediate permanent damage to the battery. If you want your battery to last long then don't discharge it to that level. A much more sane "battery empty" voltage is 3.6 V. Never let your battery get below 3.6 V and your battery will thank you for that by lasting longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it in this case, the battery has S8261-G2J battery protection chip which has undervoltage cut-off.

It will definitely cut off before battery is too empty and can get damaged.

However, there is no mention which exact version of S8261 it is. When the UVP has tripped, some versions allow recharging and some versions deny recharging.

So it is possible that the battery can go too empty and it is unchargeable via the BMS. This is because some batteries can get damaged when too empty, and manufacturer does not recommend charging again. Some manufacturers allow it, and hopefully the BMS allows charging after UVP has tripped.

It is best that the BMS is only used as the last line of protection, and your circuit should make sure it disconnects itself before BMS UVP happens, to be able to charge it.